# What glm::normalize does?

Tags: math, 3d, linear-algebra, glm-math

I trying to write an MD5 loader in Java from C++ source but I cannot find out what is this line doing:

```
animatedJoint.m_Orient = glm::normalize(animatedJoint.m_Orient);
```

where the `animatedJoint.m_Orient` is `vec4`. What does it do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's normalizing the `animatedJoint.m_Orient` vector, by taking the normal of the vector and copying it back to the vector itself.  The `glm::normalize()` method does not modify the object you pass to it.

Answer (score 16):

> What glm::normalize does?

Short answer: It normalizes a vector i.e. sets [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to 1.

#### Details

A normalized vector is one which is often used just to denote pure directions without bothering about the magnitude (set to 1; hence their other, more common name *unit vector*) i.e. how far the vector pushes doesn't matter but in what direction does it point/push matters. This also simplifies computations -- both on paper and the machine (e.g. dot products become purely cosine's result, omission of division by length, etc.)

If `v = <v.x, v.y, v.z>` some non-unit vector i.e. a vector of length/magnitude not equal to 1, then to get normalized(v), we've to divide each of its component by its length.

```cpp
vec3 normalize(const vec3 &v)
{
   float length_of_v = sqrt((v.x * v.x) + (v.y * v.y) + (v.z * v.z));
   return vec3(v.x / length_of_v, v.y / length_of_v, v.z / length_of_v);
}
```

An older term for a unit vector is [direction cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine). Say vector *v* makes an angle *α* with X-axis, *β* with Y-axis and *γ* with Z-axis then its direction cosines or the unit vector along *v* is given by `<cos α, cos β, cos γ>`. This is helpful when we don't know the components of *v* but its angles with the cardinal axes.

The reason *cosine* function and unit vectors are related will be clear with a simple example in 2D which can be extended to higher dimensions. Say for a vector

```
v = <3, 4> = 3i + 4j (3 units along X-axis and 4 units along Y-axis)
```

we're to find the unit vector u along v.

```
length of v = √(3² + 4²) = 5
u = <3/5, 4/5>
```

Now the X component (along basis *i*) 3/5 is nothing but the length along the X-axis (adjacent) divided by the length of the vector (hypotenuse), since cos α = adj/hyp = 3/5, we would've arrived at the same result if we'd known α. The same holds for Y component (along basis *j*) too, which is nothing but cos β, where β is with respect to the Y-axis, or if you want to measure it with respect to the X-axis, then it'll be 90-β which is nothing but α, that's the reason we've v = `<cos α, sin α>`, the abscissa and ordinate of a point on the unit circle, the vector from the origin to a point on the circle with length (radius) 1.

Comment: Strictly speaking, normal vectors _do_ have magnitudes. However, the point is that the magnitude is exactly equal to 1 (you know, give or take floating point rounding error) so the need to _account_ for the length vanishes in a lot of places. For example, to project onto an ordinary vector, you need to divide out the length; to project onto a normal, you don't, because the length is 1 and anything divided by 1 is itself.

Comment: @NicHartley You're right, should've been more explicit.  I guess I was trying to differentiate between unit normals and normals in general; the latter being useful for its direction than its length, which may or may not be 1, but usually 1 for simpler formulas and computation. Clarified now :)

Comment: Nice! I wasn't actually expecting a reply, haha. It's also not super important in the end -- the distinct is fairly minimal. However, in the few cases where it _does_ matter, it can really bite you in the butt not to know that normalized vectors are just normal vectors with a magnitude of 1, so I figured I'd at least clarify in a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Normalizes a vector, ie scales its elements so that returned vectors length is 1.
Many graphic related functions require passed vectors to be normalized.

Answer (score 4):

You can read more (and find answer) about this library here:

- home page: http://glm.g-truc.net/
- manual: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.3/glm-0.9.3.pdf
- method API description: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/index.html

It will help you to understand what this library is and how does it work.